# How do you GET DATA in SPSS syntax for a URL rather than local file?

Tags: spss

If you put a URL into the file path of SPSS syntax GET DATA /FILE="http:..." it doesn't work. Any suggestions to get the program to call the dataset from the web? Or is this just a program specific limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension [`SPSS GETURI DATA`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/app#/file/7b106d1c-cd47-4bea-9279-09d4f38d0c50) available from SPSS that allows you to open up sav, excel, sas or Stata datasets from online.

Otherwise you can't do it directly, but you can use the `HOST` command to set a prompt to download a file and then open it. Something like below (for my Windows machine after installing `wget`):

```
HOST = ['cd "your drive here"','wget http://www.yoururl.com/yourfile.sav'].
```

And then you should be able to open the file using normal SPSS syntax.